# Introducing The Guild of Reviewers - Better Sandbox Feedback

Tags: discussion, sandbox

(Thanks to [Redwolf Programs](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57763197#57763197) for the name!)

In a recent discussion about the info box and linking to the Sandbox for new users to use it before attempting to post their first challenge, we noted that sometimes the Sandbox can be unpleasant to use, especially for new users, as things get forgotten or don't receive attention, or after addressing all concerns the challenge immediately gets nuked into oblivion for other reasons after being posted to main.

In the interest of facilitating Sandbox usage, encouraging its use by all but especially new users, organizing feedback and discussion which would be too much clutter for comments, and overall increase the quality of challenges on our site, we are introducing:

[**The Guild of Reviewers**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123403/the-guild-of-reviewers)

This is a public chat room - anyone with 20 reputation can enter and talk - intended for users with challenge-writing experience to look at, discuss, and review sandboxed challenges. Hopefully, by discussing in chat amongst many other experienced users, rather than limiting ourselves to just adding short and non-chit-chat comments with individual concerns, we can bring better feedback and improve the quality of challenges on CGCC.

Before posting a challenge to main, if you feel that it hasn't been reviewed enough or that you want some final feedback on it before posting, this is now also a place you can ask right before posting. [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) is more active and is also somewhere you can go to ask - it is definitely on-topic. Please don't clutter either room by spamming your posts constantly, but requesting feedback on something you plan to post that has been neglected is encouraged instead of assuming it's fine and posting.